# Why CEF browser exe count is not inceasing per browser?

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

1. When I open 1 cef browser, number of cef browser exe instance is 1.
2. When I open 2 cef browser, number of cef browser exe instance is 2.
3. When I open 3 cef browser, number of cef browser exe instance is 3.
4. When I open more than 3 cef browsers, number of cef browser exe instance is still 3.

Why is this behavior? I am using 53.1.0 version of Cef.WPF.

Answer (score 0):

CEF / Chrome decide on the number of needed processes based on its own logic, mainly to save on memory.
If you want, for some reason, to match the number of process, turn on the `--process-per-site` option on start up.

https://www.ghacks.net/2015/02/08/save-memory-in-chrome-by-using-one-process-per-site/